# PHP variable fails to send by mail

Tags: php, email

i have a PHP variable that i construct like:

```
$msg_gifted='<body style="border:3px solid 
black;padding:5rem;width:1000px;margin:auto;margin-top:30px;text-
align:center;">';
$msg_gifted.='<img src="/logo.png">';
$msg_gifted.='<h1>It is a mail </h1>';
$msg_gifted.='<p>From: ';
$msg_gifted.=$_POST["useremail"];
$msg_gifted.='</p>';
$msg_gifted.='<p>Amount: GBP';
$msg_gifted.=$_POST["amount"];
$msg_gifted.='<Some text </p>';
```

then i am sending this variable with mail

```
 mail($recipient_gifted,$subject_gifted,$msg_gifted,$mailheaders_gifted);
```

everything works fine.
When i am adding some more staff to the variable then for some reason the mail never arrives

```
 $msg_gifted='<body style="border:3px solid 
black;padding:5rem;width:1000px;margin:auto;margin-top:30px;text-
align:center;">';
$msg_gifted.='<img src="/logo.png">';
$msg_gifted.='<h1>It is a mail </h1>';
$msg_gifted.='<p>From: ';
$msg_gifted.=$_POST["useremail"];
$msg_gifted.='</p>';
$msg_gifted.='<p>Amount: GBP';
$msg_gifted.=$_POST["amount"];
$msg_gifted.='<p>Some Text</p>';

$msg_gifted.='<p>';
$msg_gifted.='1000';
$msg_gifted.='</p>';
```

is there a limit for the variables?

Comment: No, its just a html in form of string stored in  variable, it looks fine

Comment: why when i add the last 3 lines it fails to send?

Comment: You have issue with 1000 ?

Comment: try to remove line above 1000, which is first in your additional code

Comment: Perhaps it is being bounced due to spam filters or some other rules. It seems extremely unlikely that those 3 lines would make it fail to send, I think you are just not receiving it.

Comment: i replaced 1000 with some text. Now the mail doesn't come. I know it is strange.

Comment: does it come or not come

Comment: no it never arrives. There are 2 more mail functions that send 2 more emails that arrive normally.

Comment: try debugging mail function . Iike $k=mail($params); var_dump($k);die;

Also check server logs ..You may get a clue from there

Comment: the server log gives me a warning about the recaptcha : PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify.........failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) for sending E-Mails.

Most likely you got something wrong with the headers of the E-Mail. It's difficult to get them right, especially, when using mail for the first time.

Also, as far as I know, there's no such thing as a variable limit for mail(),  have you already checked your server error logs?

Greetings

**Edit:**
As I thought it's a header based error.

> i figured out it has to do with the headers.
>   the whole mail headers variable is:

```
$mailheaders_gifted = "From: " . $support_email . "\r\n";
$mailheaders_gifted .= "Reply-To: ". $support_email . "\r\n";
$mailheaders_gifted .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailheaders_gifted .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

> I also tried :

```
"Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

---

I still recommend to use one of the libraries I mentioned above.

Following from the [PHP Docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for the mail function could solve the problem:

> **Note**:
>   If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail
>   transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF
>   automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This
>   should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

Comment: hi, are the above libraries standard or should i install them on my server?

Comment: Neither PHPMailer nor SwiftMailer are PHP standard libraries.
You could install them with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) or without composer. I highly recommend Composer when working with libraries in PHP.

Comment: I am working on a shared server building a form that sends the above e-mails. Is this possible to have them available or i should ask the technical guys install it for me? I dont have SSH access

Comment: I don't think that they will install Composer on this shared server for you; same for "webspace" offers across the web. You could install Composer on your local machine and upload the project via FTP to your web directory. It isn't best practice, but better then working without Composer. There a many good tutorials for working with Composer and also some for working without Composer when using PHPMailer etc.

Comment: i figured out it has to do with the headers. When i remove the $mailheaders_gifted .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; line the mails arrives but has no html styling. No matter what i tried i can make it work. I also tried : "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

Comment: the whole mail headers variable is: $mailheaders_gifted = "From: " . $support_email . "\r\n";
$mailheaders_gifted .= "Reply-To: ". $support_email . "\r\n";
$mailheaders_gifted .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailheaders_gifted .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this. it was not a problem of how to setup the variable, but how to setup the headers.
i needed to edit my headers like:

```
$mailheaders_gifted[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$mailheaders_gifted[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$mailheaders_gifted[] = 'From: My Web Site <mymail@example.com>';
```

then the mail function should be:

```
mail($recipient_gifted,$subject_gifted,$msg_gifted,implode("\r\n",$mailheaders_gifted));
```